# If I change my cassette, should I also change the chain?

Tags: chain, cassette

If I change my cassette to a new one, should I also change the chain?

I measured the chain with a wear gauge and it's ok.

Just to emphasize the obvious: I'm changing the cassette to one of exactly the same type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on how worn the chain is. If it's relatively new go ahead and use it. If it's at or approaching 0.5% stretch, just get a new one.

Comment: I have a simple wear gauge, which say `ok` or `not ok`.  How I can measure the 0.5% stretch?

Comment: How long have you had the chain, any idea of how many miles? Does the wear gauge feel like it would go in if you forced it?

Comment: About 6 months, I would estimate it as about 250 miles.
Yes, the wear gauge would go in if I force it.

Comment: 250 miles is not very much, especially if you are not riding hard.

Comment: I double-checked, actually, the gauge doesn't go in even if I force it.

Comment: At 250 miles the chain is near new unless it was (very) poor quality. I'd keep it on.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, new cassette and new chain. Keep the old one as a spare, but 250 miles is nothing and would be good to go with a new cassette. Generally you should get 2 to 3 chains per cassette.

Answer (score 1):

The consensus seems to be that a worn chain will accelerate cassette and chainring wear. I think if it’s not worn much (you could measure with a sliding caliper) you could keep using it. Otherwise install a new chain and use the current chain when it’s time for a chain replacement.

Worn chain on new chainrings can cause chain suck, but I think this is not the case for cassettes.